# Content appear outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently tried out the div with different shape like triangle trapezoid etc.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="triangle">HI nice to meet you guys</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
}
```

Previously, the content appears properly when the div is a square (height and width are 100px).

When I style the div to look like a  triangle, then the content oveflows.

How can I make this one as proportional in order to appear properly inside the div.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qbGX/2/

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Your div is invisible, it has no size, only the border is visible, so the content is overflowing.

Comment: … and the content starts exactly where expected, at the end of the left border.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply or is there is a way to show the content inside the triangle

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/TRuQc/143/)

```
.triangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 100px 173.2px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.triangle p {
    text-align: center;
    top: 80px;
    left: -47px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Fix the closing `p` tag in your fiddle, otherwise looks good. The fixed height issue could be made responsive with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your Height and width is 0. You won't fit any text into it. It will either overflow or you can set overflow to "hidden", but than you will not see anything cos the div have the size 0.

Answer (score 0):

your div is invisible to see in your actual div try to give background-color to that div.

[see demo]http://jsfiddle.net/salwenikhil0724/7qbGX/6/

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
    background-color:red;

}
.triangle p {
    text-align: center;
    top: 40px;
    left: -47px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for displayed text properly, you need to mentioned width property as follows:-

```
  <div style="width: 10em; word-wrap: break-word;">
   Some longer than expected text with antidisestablishmentarianism
  </div>
```

for Horizontal scroll you can put overflow-x:hidden its up to you dear.