# Create a triangular div using css transformation and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a triangular 'div' where I need to enter some text and a backrgound image that covers the whole 'div'.

I tried to make it using css and jquery (I used jquery so the 'triangular-element' always touch 3 vertices of 'triangular-corner')

The result is good, but the 'triangular-content' is not centered within it.

I've applied the inverse transformation to 'triangular-content' in order to get it back un-rotated but after that i can't get it centered within the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/simonepri/c6aukfzj/1/

I've create a snippet to show you the problem.

If you change the page you can see that the yellow area ('triangular-content') not cover whole black div ('triangular-element').
Here is an image that show the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYJcj.jpg
How can i center the yellow div???

```js
$( window ).ready(function() {
  var angle = Math.atan($(".triangle-corner").height()/$(window).width());
  $(".triangle-element").css("transform", 'rotate(' + -angle + 'rad)');
  $(".triangle-content").css("transform", 'rotate(' + angle + 'rad)');
});

 $( window ).resize(function() {
  var angle = Math.atan($(".triangle-corner").height()/$(window).width());
  $(".triangle-element").css("transform", 'rotate(' + -angle + 'rad)');
  $(".triangle-content").css("transform", 'rotate(' + angle + 'rad)');
});
```

```css
#what-i-do {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
#wid-designer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

.triangle-corner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.triangle-element {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: #000;
  right: 0px;
  top:-100%;
}
.triangle-content {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width:  66.666666666666666666%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  right: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  top:100%;
  font-size: 40pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="what-i-do">  <!-- 1 -->
  <section id="wid-designer">
    <div class="triangle-corner"><div class="triangle-element"><div class="triangle-content">
        the yellow div need to fill the balck div and need to be centered (0 margin in all direction)
 </div></div></div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
This question is not a duplicate of:
[CSS triangle containing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text)
As it use a css hack (border-color) in order to create a triangle that cannot be styled with background-image and background-position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS triangle containing text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text)

Comment: Is not a duplicate as it use a css hack in order to create a trinagle that cannot be styled with background-image and background-position.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling a little with the css values for `left`, `top`, `width` and `padding-left` got me a completely yellow triangle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbpnam7e/

The main issue seemed to be the use of:

```
width:  66.666666666666666666%;
```

Comment: Try to move the slider in order to shrink the page and you'll see that the black is shown again.

Comment: I need 
width:  66.666666666666666666%;
in order to give to 'triangle-content' the same width of 'triangle-corner'
Since 'triangle-element' has:
width: 150%;
The only way to restore the width of 'triangle-content' is to solve this:
150/100 = 100/x

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing rotate() to skewY() has solved my problems, now works perfectly.
Thanks anyway for your help.