# Trying to reproduce a clipping effect with slanted margin in CSS

Tags: css, image, text

Answer not found in source above.

---

[Effect to Reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6sbp.png)

Looks like two stacked objects (`img` & `div`) with one sliced and arranged on top. Notice that the text also follows the slanted margin along the slice. What should I use to get the diagonal slice, and what should I use to achieve the slanted margin?

---

I suspect I need to use clip-path or clipPath, but not sure how to achieve a polygon clip based on the specific geometry of the image or div, whichever is clipped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: *without using Adobe, and therfore enriching my SEO* - I'm not clear on how this is related to your problem. You should make your question title reflect the problem when you add your code.

Comment: Just started reading [here](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/), so no code yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS triangle containing text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text)

Comment: @BSMP, actually the code there does not achieve what is being asked in my question. That is simply centered text in a triangle, not a slanted margin.

Comment: You only looked at the first answer?

Comment: @BSMP, apparently so, thanks, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `shape-outside` css property to have the text follow slanted margin. [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

```
.element {  
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

You can use `clip-path` to clip the image. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('/path/to/image') center no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
}
```