# How to write text inside inverted-trapezoid (shape)?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to write text in  inverted-trapezoid . I saw many solution that how to put text inside a trapezoid shape but haven't found a single code for  inverted-trapezoid .

All I want is to put my text inside the inverted triangle   :(

Thank you <3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.trapezoid2 {
 width: 23px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 140px solid #20a3bf;
    border-left: 70px solid transparent;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="trapezoid2 ">thanks</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use CSS for what it was meant for. This is a job for [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS triangle containing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text)

Comment: @D.Pardal I didn't understand ?????????????

Comment: @D.Pardal i haven't get it :(

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make it responsive

Comment: @ShamirKhan You should use [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) to create polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the similar question I shared in the comment doesn't help, here's another way with CSS pseudo classes. The caveat being the text is in the CSS instead of the `div`

```css
.trapezoid2 {
  width: 23px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 140px solid #20a3bf;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}

.trapezoid2::after {
  content: "Thanky";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: -10px;
}


/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .trapezoid2 {
    border-top-color: red;
  }
}


/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .trapezoid2 {
    border-top-color: #bf2090;
  }
}


/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .trapezoid2 {
    border-top-color: rebeccapurple;
  }
}


/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .trapezoid2 {
    border-top-color: cyan;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you but can you tell me about what is this after  " ::after  "

Comment: Hi, there's too much to share in a limited comment area. You can learn more about css pseudo-classes at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements

 or try any free css lessons from freecodecamp or codecademy. Good Luck!

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make it responsive

Comment: I've updated the answer with a quick example. The trapezoid changes color based on the browser size. There are many free resources out there explaining in depth how media queries and responsive design work.

Comment: Sorry I can't help without seeing your code. The code example above works, but it's possible something in your code is invalid or missing. I'd suggest creating a local [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and slowly add pieces of your CSS back in to see what might be the issue.