# Rotated shape but still parallel to the left border of the screen

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if there is a way to align the div and its content to the left border of my screen but I need to keep the rotation.
So the text is parallel to the border of the screen.
(The div should not be a rectangle anymore but I need to keep the text orientation)

Later I'll change the font so it compensate the orientation, but I'm looking for something similar to this, without the centered text

Here is a snippet so you can see what I have for now.
[image: example]

```css
div{
  background-color: red;
  width:25vw;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  margin-top:20vh;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores assumenda quo quas? Reprehenderit, in sint harum expedita similique maiores assumenda inventore! Fuga ullam consectetur similique quas omnis facilis eius minus?</div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: the font can be aligned to the screen with a specific oblique font, what I would like is that text orientation, but on the other side it stays parallel on the left to the screen border

Comment: You want to achieve exactly what is showed in the image you posted? I still can't understand.

Comment: I have edited the image so it's maybe better now :)

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure about that, but do you have any clue on what to do ?

Comment: Maybe try to rotate a triangular element like the one showed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113682/1947677) answer. It would be very inelegant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need `transform-origin` ?

EDIT : Did you know `transform: skew(__deg)` ?

```css
div{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-15deg);
  margin-top:20vh;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

div span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br>
  <span>Sit amet</span><br>
  <span>...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this can help, thanks, but I have edited my question so it's clearer maybe :)

Comment: Thanks, that's not what I asked for though, because I can just have a font to do that, I don't need to do it manually :)

Comment: Yes, i've seen the previous image. Working on it.

Comment: New sample with `skew`